# Upgrading jQuery UI from 1.8.6 to 1.10.3 tabsselect alternative?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Upgrading.. and trying to find a way of finding when a tab is selected so I can do so pre/post data rendering when the tab is selected. However I have hit a snag..

Original way of handling it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#storage").bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui)
    {
        if (ui.index === 1)
        {
            //run some code here
        }
        if (ui.index === 2)
        {
            //run some other code here.. 
        }
    });
});
```

Trying to piece something similar together from what I gather from docs and google searches..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var doTabAction = function(e, tab)
        {
            console.log(tab.newTab.index());
        }
        $("#storage").tabs({
            beforeActivate: doTabAction
        });
});
```

problem it seems is as of 1.9 `tabsselect` was removed. Changed to "active" or "beforeActive" of which doesn't appear to work for me.. or it might, but not the way I was expecting. So I am hoping someone will know this answer or can assist in helping me figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [activate event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#storage").tabs().on('tabsactivate', function (event, ui) {
        var index = ui.newTab.index();
        console.log('index', index)
        if (index == 0) {
            console.log('first')
        } else if (index == 1) {
            console.log('second')
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kcDBe/)